cmdstanpy - ERROR using Prophet from meta
I'm trying to use meta's prophet library for forescast and I keep getting the same error when fitting my data frame.
I'm using a virtual environment, python 3.1, prophet 1.1.6, holidays=0.58, cmdstanpy=1.2.4
Log error
14:54:18 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] start processing
14:54:18 - cmdstanpy - INFO - Chain [1] done processing
14:54:18 - cmdstanpy - ERROR - Chain [1] error: terminated by signal 3221225657 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MuriloXavierDeSousa\PycharmProjects\cash-flow\.venv\lib\site-packages\prophet\forecaster.py", line 1232, in fit
    self.params = self.stan_backend.fit(stan_init, dat, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MuriloXavierDeSousa\PycharmProjects\cash-flow\.venv\lib\site-packages\prophet\models.py", line 125, in fit
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\MuriloXavierDeSousa\PycharmProjects\cash-flow\.venv\lib\site-packages\prophet\models.py", line 121, in fit
    self.stan_fit = self.model.optimize(**args)
  File "C:\Users\MuriloXavierDeSousa\PycharmProjects\cash-flow\.venv\lib\site-packages\cmdstanpy\model.py", line 659, in optimize
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Error during optimization! Command 'C:\Users\MuriloXavierDeSousa\PycharmProjects\cash-flow\.venv\Lib\site-packages\prophet\stan_model\prophet_model.bin random seed=76105 data file=C:\Users\MURILO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyeys75p7\uuozwjja.json init=C:\Users\MURILO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyeys75p7\glhxw1po.json output file=C:\Users\MURILO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyeys75p7\prophet_modelf0ftxvye\prophet_model-20241015145418.csv method=optimize algorithm=newton iter=10000' failed: 


I've already installed the c++ compilers, changed the paths in the system path, changed the versions of the libraries, read everything on the internet but I still get the same error. I've already reinstalled cmdstan using cmdstanpy, everything works, but when I fit, I get the same error.
import  cmdstanpy
cmdstanpy.install_cmdstan(compiler=True, overwrite=True)

